# How to compare rows (one row to the other row) of two different matrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to compare rows of two different matrices and find out which rows match.

For example: `A= [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 1 2 3];
             B= [1 2 3; 4 5 8; 7 8 9; 7 7 7]`

Then I want to compare the first row of A with the first row of B, the second row of A with the second row of B etc. If they do not match, it should return a logical 0 or false and vice versa. Say, if C is the output column vector then,
            `C = [ 1; 0; 1; 0]`

Is there any MatLAB function like `ismember`. The problem with  `ismember` is that it does not compare row wise but compares if a row in A exist in B.

Comment: You can compare them directly with `==`, it just returns a logical array.

Comment: @excaza then again i would have to use `all(C,2)` to obtain the column vector right?

Comment: Yes, something like `test = all(A==B, 2);` works fine

Comment: @excaza oh yes it does. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
N=size(A,1);
C=zeros(N,1);

for k=1:N

C(k)=isequal(A(k,:),B(k,:));

end
```

Without the loop (credits to excaza) :

```
C=all(A==B,2);
```

Comment: thank you very much. although `excaza` had mentioned it just before you did.

Comment: Yup, just saw that, i'll just let the loop implementation in my answer

Comment: @BillBokeey no need to edit it out, it's a simple answer.